# Mysql export issue?

Tags: mysql

I am using the following command to export thedabase,however i can't find the FILE.sql file after executing the command.Where is it stored?

```
 mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name > FILE.sql
```

Also how can i check my home directory , I have checked the program files(x86) mysql and respective bin folder in it.

Comment: It is stored in the [working directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory).

Comment: You can export the dump to any location `mysqldump -u username -ppassword database_name > /path/to/FILE.sql`

Answer (score 0):

The other way to export data to CSV file is by using "OUTFILE" syntax provided by MySQL like shown below.

```
[Usual MySQL Query]
INTO OUTFILE '/var/data_exports/huge_data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Read practical usage and more here. [ResolveBug.com](http://resolvebug.com/mysql-export-huge-data-milliseconds/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be at either the root dir or in current dir where you run the dump command.